# Should I install broadcom-sta-dkms for better bluetooth connection on a Macbook?

Tags: networking, drivers, bluetooth, 22.04, broadcom

In Kubuntu 22.04 on a Macbook Air I have some problems  with a bluetooth speaker that I didn't had on a PC: it has [no sound after media pause](https://askubuntu.com/q/1425258/925128).

```
hciconfig -a
hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: USB
        BD Address: B8:E8:56:25:CC:65  ACL MTU: 1021:8  SCO MTU: 64:1
        UP RUNNING PSCAN 
        RX bytes:1294011 acl:1189 sco:0 events:180587 errors:0
        TX bytes:306030915 acl:360235 sco:0 commands:219 errors:0
        Features: 0xbf 0xfe 0xcf 0xfe 0xdb 0xff 0x7b 0x87
        Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
        Link policy: RSWITCH SNIFF 
        Link mode: PERIPHERAL ACCEPT 
        Name: 'cip-MacBookAir'
        Class: 0x7c010c
        Service Classes: Rendering, Capturing, Object Transfer, Audio, Telephony
        Device Class: Computer, Laptop
        HCI Version: 4.0 (0x6)  Revision: 0x21d0
        LMP Version: 4.0 (0x6)  Subversion: 0x414f
        Manufacturer: Broadcom Corporation (15)
```

Looking for a solution for "Broadcom" I have found I already use a proprietary driver but that there is another one called `broadcom-sta-dkms`.

[image]

[Here](https://packages.debian.org/fr/stretch/broadcom-sta-dkms) is what I have found about it:

> Broadcom STA is a binary-only device driver to support the following
> IEEE 802.11a/b/g/n wireless network cards: BCM4311-, BCM4312-,
> BCM4313-, BCM4321-, BCM4322-, BCM43142-, BCM43224-, BCM43225-,
> BCM43227-, BCM43228-, BCM4331-, BCM4360-, and BCM4352-based hardware.
>
> This package provides the source code for the wl kernel modules and
> makes use of the DKMS build utility to install them for the running
> kernel. The alternative package broadcom-sta-source can be used
> instead in case of build problems.
>
> The wireless-tools package is also required in order to make use of
> these modules. Kernel source or headers are required to compile these
> modules.

Should I install it to improve my bluetooth performance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`broadcom-sta-dkms` is completely unrelated to Bluetooth. It is a Wi-Fi driver.

So it won't affect anything.

Also `broadcom-sta-dkms` and the installed `bcmwl-kernel-source` is the same driver.

So it won't change anything related to Wi-Fi as well.

Comment: Isn't the wireless hardware and driver the same for bluetooth? - If not,  how can investigate its drivers?

Comment: BT device can be combined with Wi-Fi, but drivers are different. You can ask about the real problem.  What you asked is [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I have posted a link to my previous question.  I have asked how to fix my bluetooth problem, obviously in relation to drivers, but I have no answers. I was looking for one and that's how the above came about.

Comment: It is OK. I'll look there.

Comment: Any idea how to get the name of the bluetooth hardware?

Comment: `lsusb` will show it. But there is no much what you can do with drivers. The problem is not in the kernel drivers IMHO.

Comment: I have fixed the problem: nothing to do with the kernel or the drivers, it is a problem with the Plasma BT tool. The fix is to keep runing `blueman-manager` (NOT just `blueaman` and `blueman-tray`!): [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1493695/925128) is my answer.